# Transition on page re-visit

Tags: css, transition, pageload

I have a simple transform & transition on a div element. However, it doesn't appear to be working on page loads/re-visits.
Really appreciate if I could be directed to a possible solution.

```css
.container {
    width: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    background: #ccff44;
    padding: 50px 5px;
    border: #000 2px solid;
    margin: auto;
    transform: translate3D(-50px, 0, 0);
    transition: all 2s ease-in;    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>Main paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello I think what you are looking for is an animation

the transition will not trigger any movement on its own

```css
@keyframes enter {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-50px);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
}
.container {
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ccff44;
  padding: 50px 5px;
  border: #000 2px solid;
  margin: auto;
  animation: enter 2s linear;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <p>Main paragraph</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: In addition to this answer: if you want the transition, you will have to add another class when loading the page with the transform property. As you are using it right now (OP), it will load with the transform already applied, and transition won't apply until you change the transform.